# Trying to post data using ngResource module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am desperately trying to call a simple save on my object using angular ng-resource module.

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ngResource'])
.controller('testController', function($scope, Stock) {
    $scope.stock = {};
    $scope.stock.id = 1;
    $scope.stock.name = "Kellog"; 

    $scope.submit = function() {    
      Stock.save($scope.stock); 
    };
});

angular.module('testApp')
.factory('Stock', function($resource) {
    return $resource('api/stock');
  }
);
```

I expect to have my data posted (POST verb) but nothing happens, instead I got the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

One must create the resource object first

```
var newStock = new Stock($scope.stock);

newStock.$save();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but no luck, here is the new error I got: TypeError: Stock is not a constructor

Answer (score -1):

In my first message there is one very important info missing, the js library I was using. In that case ng-resource.js which is not compatible with one of the latest angular revision (1.5.3 for that matter). Instead one should use angular-resource.js.

I did a little change in my code (use of a promise) and everything went smooth thereafter so here is my answer:

```
angular.module('testApp', ['ngResource'])
.controller('testController', function($scope, Stock) {
    $scope.stock = {};
    $scope.stock.id = 1;
    $scope.stock.name = "Kellog";


    $scope.submit = function() {  
      new Stock($scope.stock).$save()    
      .then(function(response) {
        $scope.stock = response;
      })
    };
});

angular.module('testApp')
.factory('Stock', function($resource) {
    return $resource('api/stock');
  }
);
```